# SQL Log File is over 70 GB

Tags: sql, logging, backup

The issue is that the I've a SQL log file for the exceeded 70 GB causing problems in sharing the data among the sites .. our SW provider said that we have to backup the log file and then archive it and finally create a new one ?!
 Is that correct?! Or there is a different procedure we can use , what would be the best scenario in this case ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: On linux system that's usually logrotate's job. if your log file grows fast that might be you have set your db server to be overly verbose. That being said, i think this question fit more serverfault than stack overflow.